# React.findDOMNode(component) list of methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there is `React.findDOMNode(component).value/focus()`. I am looking for all the methods can be used with `React.findDOMNode`.

For example, I have an `<input type='checkbox' ref='component' />` tag, and I tried `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.component).selected` (I dont know if it exists), and there is nothing.

Answer (score 4):

`React.findDOMNode` is described by the [Top-Level API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html):

> ```
> DOMElement findDOMNode(ReactComponent component)
> ```
>
> If this component has been mounted into the DOM, this returns the corresponding native browser DOM element. This method is useful for reading values out of the DOM, such as form field values and performing DOM measurements. When `render` returns `null` or `false`, `findDOMNode` returns `null`.

The value returned is a native [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)—not a React-specific type, which is why it's not covered by the React documentation.

Comment: Thanks for more explanations @Chris ... I tried `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.component).checked` and it works (return a boolean\).

Answer (score 0):

You can always assign an event and use `event.currentTarget.value`