# How to manipulate attributes from ref selector

Tags: attributes, reactjs, selector

I'd like to add a `disabled` attribute to the element that has `ref="formButton"`, I tried this and it didn't seem to work:

```
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.formButton).attr('disabled')
this.refs.formButton.attr('disabled')
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32200318/356380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'React' way of doing this is to control the button's `disabled` attribute in the render method, and using the component's state to keep track of it.

For example:

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { disabled: false };
  },

  disableFormButton: function() {
    this.setState({ disabled: true });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <button
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
          onClick={this.disableFormButton.bind(this)}>
          Disable
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15712/)

Note that you no longer need the `ref`, as you don't need to access the DOM node from outside the `render` method.

See [*Thinking in React*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state) from the React.js documentation for more information about what should be stored in a component's state, and what should be passed as properties.

> **For those reading in 2020 and later**
>
> Since the introduction of the [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) in React, you can rewrite the example here using a functional component.
>
> ```js
> const myComponent = () => {
>   const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false)
>   return (
>     <button
>       disabled={disabled}
>       onClick={() => setDisabled(true)}>
>         Disable
>     </button>
>   )
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Use standard [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) for this, like:

```
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.formButton).setAttribute('disabled', true)
```

Or, if you want to use jquery:

```
$(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.formButton)).attr('disabled')
```

Comment: This isn't the React way. You should only be setting attributes on DOM elements directly when interfacing with an external/3rd-party (i.e. non-React) component/library.

Comment: What about using a React component such as something from the material-ui lib, where you need to set an attribute on the one of the inputs that is generated by the TextField control? How would this be done in the React way?